# neo4j-shell "connection refused" error

Tags: shell, neo4j

I'm running 2.0.0 M06 on a Mac (ML)

Neo4j is running and the web console works fine. But when I try to connect via Neo4j-shell it fails. Everything was fine on Wednesday, but after attempting a Postgres install (part of the MusicBrainz Neo4j project) this problem came up:

```
sneedham-pd:neo4j-community-2.0.0-M06 username$ **bin/neo4j start**
Using additional JVM arguments:  -server -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -Dorg.neo4j.server.properties=conf/neo4j-server.properties -Djava.util.logging.config.file=conf/logging.properties -Dlog4j.configuration=file:conf/log4j.properties -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled
Starting Neo4j Server...WARNING: not changing user
process [694]... waiting for server to be ready..... OK.
http://localhost:7474/ is ready.

sneedham-pd:neo4j-community-2.0.0-M06 username$ **bin/neo4j-shell -v**
ERROR (-v for expanded information):
    Connection refused
java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 172.16.31.31; nested exception is: 
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:619)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:216)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:202)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:128)
    at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invokeRemoteMethod(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:194)
    at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:148)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1.welcome(Unknown Source)
    at org.neo4j.shell.impl.AbstractClient.sayHi(AbstractClient.java:206)
    at org.neo4j.shell.impl.RemoteClient.findRemoteServer(RemoteClient.java:63)
    at org.neo4j.shell.impl.RemoteClient.<init>(RemoteClient.java:55)
    at org.neo4j.shell.impl.RemoteClient.<init>(RemoteClient.java:43)
    at org.neo4j.shell.ShellLobby.newClient(ShellLobby.java:165)
    at org.neo4j.shell.StartClient.startRemote(StartClient.java:289)
    at org.neo4j.shell.StartClient.start(StartClient.java:167)
    at org.neo4j.shell.StartClient.main(StartClient.java:119)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:391)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:425)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:208)
    at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIDirectSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIDirectSocketFactory.java:40)
    at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIMasterSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIMasterSocketFactory.java:146)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:613)
    ... 14 more

 -host      Domain name or IP of host to connect to (default: localhost)
 -port      Port of host to connect to (default: 1337)
 -name      RMI name, i.e. rmi://<host>:<port>/<name> (default: shell)
 -pid       Process ID to connect to
 -c         Command line to execute. After executing it the shell exits
 -file      File containing commands to execute. After executing it the shell exits
 -readonly  Connect in readonly mode
 -path      Points to a neo4j db path so that a local server can be started there
 -config    Points to a config file when starting a local server

Example arguments for remote:
    -port 1337
    -host 192.168.1.234 -port 1337 -name shell
    -host localhost -readonly
    ...or no arguments for default values
Example arguments for local:
    -path /path/to/db
    -path /path/to/db -config /path/to/neo4j.config
    -path /path/to/db -readonly
```

Comment: I am still unable to launch the Neo4j shell. Using command line options, as suggested by Michael below, doesn't work. Anyone know how to regain use of localhost via shell? I don't know why it's routed to 172.16.31.31.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is that server is bound to `localhost` (127.0.0.1) and the shell tries to connect to `172.16.31.31`, that is another network interface, not loopback. That is the reason why you get here `connection refused`.

Comment: Thanks. Now, where do I change the configuration that is trying to connect to 172.16.31.31? Seems some install process hi-jacked my shell. Do I use ifconfig?

Comment: You can try to use `-host 127.0.0.1 -port 1337` as command line options for the shell. And check your `/etc/hosts` for the localhost DNS lookup

Comment: Sadly I am not getting the expected result:

sneedham-pd:neo4j-community-2.0.0-M06 username$ bin/neo4j-shell -host 127.0.0.1 -port 1337 -v
ERROR (-v for expanded information):
 Connection refused
java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 172.16.31.31;

Comment: We've found that this is something on our local network. When I use other networks, it's fine. Still haven't found the cause, but it's not a Neo4j-shell or host issue. Thanks!

Comment: @roymond can you elaborate what is the network issue you found. I am having the same problem

Answer (score 6):

In your neo4j.conf you have to uncomment the lines related to using the neo4j-shell

```
# Enable a remote shell server which Neo4j Shell clients can log in to.
dbms.shell.enabled=true
# The network interface IP the shell will listen on (use 0.0.0.0 for all interfaces).
dbms.shell.host=127.0.0.1
# The port the shell will listen on, default is 1337.
dbms.shell.port=1337
```

This fixed the issue for me

Comment: Thanks, it worked. This seems like is the solution for using it right now, but I want to add a note that it says that neo4j-shell will be deprecated in the future

Answer (score 1):

Open command prompt: [image]

C:\Users\nsh004\Documents\Neo4j>Neo4jShell -path C:\Users\nshinde004\Documen
ts\Neo4j\Demo1 -file load.cql

This worked for me. we have to provide the path for database. Once I provided it worked!! :-)

Comment: Thanks, this worked. Be aware that you have to stop the database if you started it earlier (via neo4j console for example), and in windows you can't have spaces in the path to your file. (2018, on Windows 10)

Answer (score 0):

I faced with the same issue.

My configuration is:

- windows-7-x32
- neo4j-2.1.4
- neo4j starts as a service

The Neo4jShell.bat works file util I close my notebook (sleep mode).
After resume, looks like neo4j process somehow "loose" port to listen.
Depends on situation 1337 port could be used by different processes

[nvstreamsvc.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:1337         notebook:0             LISTENING

[Dropbox.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:1337         notebook:0             LISTENING

In my case solution is to restart Neo4j-Server service via Windows Task Manager.

I hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

You can export neo4j database without host if you have database folder using following command :

```
neo4j-shell -path /var/lib/neo4j/data/databases/graph.db -c dump > export_data.cypher -v
```

It will create file called "export_data.cypher" in your current directory.

Hope it helps.